# Is it possible to href more than one link?

Tags: html, ejs, anchor, bootstrap-5

In my website I'm using an anchor tag that link to another page:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= term._id %>"><%= term.term %></a></li>
```

I need to add one more href link which is:

```
 href="#list-item-1"
```

Is it possible to add more than one href links in the same anchor tag.

The idea is that is that the anchor tag will redirect to another page and scroll down to a specific part of the page

Comment: How do you trying to work with 2 links? What will happen when you click it?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to two pages at a time ?

Comment: No, since part after `#` is treated as single element. Also, how do you imagine browser _jumping_ to two different links _at same time_?

Comment: i want to scroll down in the  existing page

Comment: you can do this : `<a href = "new.html#list-item-1">` note the use of two things side by side .

Comment: You want to scroll down existing page AND what else? Why the two hrefs?

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= term._id %>#list-item-1"><%= term.term %></a>`

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append the hash at the end of the regular link:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= term._id %>#list-item-1"><%= term.term %></a>
```

Make sure there's no `/` or space between the `term._id` and the hash value.

That link when activated will load the URL provided, then jump to whereever the element with `id="list-item-1"` is located.